# How to get a php variable of Joomla article title?

Tags: php, joomla

I created Joomla articles with content and forms representing a quiz. Users fill in the forms, actually their answers and then submit it.

After that, the `congratulation.php` page opens (code below) and my database gets filled with data. It should fill in columns like id and answer. But the problem is that I cannot achieve my id variable, that should point on the article id of the article where the quiz was.

```
<?php
echo 'WELL DONE!!!<br/>';
$answer1 = $_POST['answer1'];   

$db =& JFactory::getDBO(); 
$query = "INSERT INTO quiz(id, answer1) 
VALUES ((select id from jos_content where title='$title'), '$answer1')"; 
$db->setQuery($query); 
$db->query();
?>
```

HOW to define $title variable. The `$title` variable should be for example "Pet's quiz". I can do it manually, but how to create this to recognize the article and put the title of it in `mysql`.

Comment: Where are you defining your `$title` variable? Also, have you tried using some sort of quote marks around the `$title` variable in your query? :)

Comment: Yes I tried. But the $title isn't defined. The problem is how to define this. I have a title of Joomla article, but when user clicks submit, it redirects them to congratulation page where there is no title of the article anymore. So I cannot pass it to the database with the code above.

Comment: Hmm, is there any way to get the `$title` via `$_POST`?

Comment: I was thinking about this, but how to achieve this. There is no form on the article page where users should type the article title. Maybe there is some $_POST method that could transfer variable from one to another file? I have a variable $title on the article page...

Comment: Are there any ?title or &title related values in the URL? If so, maybe something there could be retrieved using [`$_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) ...

Comment: What's your joomla version?

Comment: Could you show us the form which posts answer1?

Comment: Joomla 3.0. And the form is textarea <textarea name="answer1" rows="3" required="required"></textarea>

Comment: I have a kind of solution. On the article page I have to make manually form field (input text) with initial value of $title variable. So when users submit the article form, the $_POST method catches the title. And I hide the fake input field with CSS. It works. But the solution is disastrous.

Comment: You don't need to hide it, just use hidden input field. However the actual solution is using a hidden input field that will hold the current article id, the you get the article title before you write info in your table.